# how combine multiple order into one order by order number in mssql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to retrieve all the order that have sold particular products that I'm looking for. For example some orders might only have one item and some orders might have multiple items. I want to combine with all the items on the order into one row. Here are my script that returns all the products that I'm looking for:

```
select 
distinct a.SOPNUMBE as 'Order No.', 
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%CLK' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'Clicks Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%CLK' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Clicks Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%105' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'Smart Sensor Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%105' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Smart Sensors Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%125' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'HD Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%125' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'HD Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%sen' then COUNT(*) else 0 End)  as 'Sensor Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%sen' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Sensors Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%Mat' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'Matrix Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%Mat' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Matrix Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%200' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'Advance Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%200' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Advance Total'

from SOP30300 a join IV00101 b

on a.ITEMNMBR = b.ITEMNMBR

join sop30200 c

on a.SOPNUMBE = c.SOPNUMBE

where (a.SOPNUMBE like 'INV%')


group by a.SOPNUMBE, ITMCLSCD

order by SOPNUMBE
```

**The result looks like this:**

```
Order No.   Clicks Counts   Clicks Total    Smart Sensor Counts Smart Sensors Total HD Counts   HD Total    Sensor Counts   Sensors Total   Matrix Counts   Matrix Total    Advance Counts  Advance Total
001 2   537 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
001 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
002 1   277.46  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
002 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   80  0   0   0   0
003 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   450 0   0   0   0
003 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   5200
003 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
003 6   1483.09 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
004 1   1400    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
004 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   875 0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code with subquery. Query is parse correctly. Hope this help

you might have error.

```
Select 
[Order No],
Sum([Clicks Total]),
Sum([Smart Sensor Counts]),
Sum([Smart Sensors Total]),
Sum([HD Counts]),
Sum([HD Total]),
Sum([Sensor Counts]),
Sum([Sensors Total]),
Sum([Matrix Counts]),
Sum([Matrix Total]),
Sum([Advance Counts]),
Sum([Advance Total ]),
(
select 
distinct a.SOPNUMBE as 'Order No.', 
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%CLK' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'Clicks Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%CLK' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Clicks Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%105' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'Smart Sensor Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%105' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Smart Sensors Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%125' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'HD Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%125' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'HD Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%sen' then COUNT(*) else 0 End)  as 'Sensor Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%sen' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Sensors Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%Mat' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'Matrix Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%Mat' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Matrix Total',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%200' then COUNT(*) else 0 End) as 'Advance Counts',
(case when ITMCLSCD like '%200' then sum(XTNDPRCE) else 0 End) as 'Advance Total'

from SOP30300 a join IV00101 b

on a.ITEMNMBR = b.ITEMNMBR

join sop30200 c

on a.SOPNUMBE = c.SOPNUMBE

where (a.SOPNUMBE like 'INV%')


group by a.SOPNUMBE, ITMCLSCD

--order by SOPNUMBE
) as t 
Group  by [Order No]
order by [Order No]
```